# copying unique filtered column values VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that have logins in one column and phone numbers in another. I need to copy all phone numbers of each login and paste them to another sheet. But i need only unique phone numbers as one login may contain many records with the same phone number. What i have tried and what failed

```
For Each rCell In Sheets("PotentialFraud").Range("B1:B" & IndexValueLastRow("B:B"))
    .Range("A2").AutoFilter _
    field:=12, _
    Criteria1:=rCell.Value2
    LastRow = .Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).End(xlDown).Row
    .Range("P1:P" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Worksheets("PotentialFraud").Range(rCell.Offset(0, 2).Address).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Next rCell
```

This Method does not give me an option to copy only unique values.
Another option I found was to use Advanced Filter

```
   .Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Worksheets("PotentialFraud").Range("A:A"), _
        Unique:=True
```

However, this lead to error 1004 saying either **This command requires at least two rows of source data...** even though there are 2500 rows visible. Either **Application-defined or object-defined error** if i change the range to

```
    .Range("P:P" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AdvancedFilter _
Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=Worksheets("PotentialFraud").Range("A:A"), _
Unique:=True
```

*("P2:P") to ("P:P")*

Comment: why are you offsetting if You know where the phone numbers are? In the last example you forget to define your first row P2, instead you have "P:P"&LastRow, you are working with multiple worksheets, are you in a With block in your snippet, the last way you list is close to how I do it

Comment: I have headers, thats why i use P2 in the first example, and in the second, i missed P2 intentionally, as you may see its the only difference between example 1 and 2, that way i get another error. Yes, the offset may be removed, it was there because for some reason, even having P2 would still copy the header when the data is filtered

Comment: Are you looking for unique login-phone pairs? Or simply unique phone numbers?

Comment: unique login-phone pairs

Comment: The unique pairs are supposed to go into the `PotentialFraud` worksheet?

Comment: Well, technically yes. More precisely, PF sheet have some logins that are used to filter another table that contains logins and numbers (Main table)  and paste unique numbers back to PF nearby their logins

Comment: Yes you have to put the attribute in that there is a header and it wont do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you just use the onboard remove duplicates function in excel?
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2

Or in VBA:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=xlYes
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want unique login-phone pairs (and not just unique phones), you could issue an SQL statement against the worksheet, and use **CopyFromRecordset** to paste it into a new worksheet.

Add a reference to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library** (via **Tools** -> **References...**). There may be versions other than 6.1; choose the highest.

Assuming the logins are in column `A` and the phone numbers are in column `P`, and the source data's sheet name is `RawData`, you could then write the following:

```
Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"""

Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT DISTINCT F1, F16 " & _
    "FROM [RawData$A:P]"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString

Worksheets("PotentialFraud").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Notes:

- If you want to exclude headers from the data, set `HDR=Yes` instead of `HDR=No` in the connection string. In that case, the field names will not be autodefined (e.g. `F1`, `F2` etc.) but will be the names defined in the first row; the SQL should be adjusted accordingly (e.g. `SELECT Login, Phone ...` instead of `SELECT F1, F16 ...`)
- The code which reads in the data (until the last line, which actually pastes the data into the worksheet) requires only the ActiveX Data Objects object library, and is thus independent of any given host or host object model. You only need the path to the Excel file, instead of `ActiveWorkbook.FullName`.

---

Alternatively, you could use a Dictionary. (Add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**.)

Choose some character that won't appear in either the login or the phone, and use the concatenated login+character+phone as the key of the dictionary. (In the code below, I am using `~`.)

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value

Dim separator As String
separator = "~"

Dim dict As New Dictionary
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    dict(arr(i, 1) & separator & arr(i, 2)) = 1 'dummy value
Next
```

Then, you can iterate over the keys, split the key on the character, and write the parts into the appropriate destination cells.

```
arr = dict.Keys
For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    Dim key As String
    key = arr(i)

    With Worksheets("PotentialFraud")
        .Range(.Cells(i + 1, 1), .Cells(i + 1, 2)).Value = Split(key, separator)
    End With
Next
```

---

Even better than iterating over the keys, you could write the returned array from the `Keys` method into the Value property of an appropriately sized Range, and then call TextToColumns on the Range.

```
'Fill dictionary, as above

arr = dict.Keys
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("PotentialFraud").Range("A1:A" & (UBound(arr) + 1))
rng.Value = dict.Keys
rng.TextToColumns Other:=True, otherchar:=separator
```

---

#### References

ActiveX Data Objects

- [**Recordset** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado?view=sql-server-2017), [**Open** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-method-ado-recordset?view=sql-server-2017)

Excel

- [**Worksheets** collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheets-object-excel), [**Add** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheets-add-method-excel)
- [**Worksheet** object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-object-excel), [**Range** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-range-property-excel), [**Cells** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-cells-property-excel)
- [**Range** object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel), [**CopyFromRecordset** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cec7fded-f4e0-1b1c-5374-8a860828c9cc%28office.15%29.aspx), [**TextToColumns** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel), [**Value** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value-property-excel)

Scripting Runtime

- [**Dictionary** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/x4k5wbx4%28v%3dvs.84%29) [**Keys** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/etzd1tzc%28v%3dvs.84%29)

VBA

- [**UBound** function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ubound-function), [**Split** function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function)